# Constrain objec properties to be object with properties whose keys must be the same in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-constraints

I am creating a sectional form. Each section must have initial values, and a validation schema.  To help the team develop in a consistent way, I want to make sure that each `section` looks like this:

```
interface Section {
  initialValues: { [key: string]: any };
  validationSchema: { [key: string]: Yup.AnySchema };
}
```

Is there a way to constrain `initialValues` and `validationSchema` so that they must contain the same keys?

I.e., this will work:

```
const section1: Section = {
  initialValues: {
    name: "",
    age: undefined // will be a number
  },
  validationSchema: {
    name: Yup.string().required(),
    age: Yup.number().required()
  }
}
```

Whereas this would break:

```
const section1: Section = {
  initialValues: {
    name: "",
    age: undefined // will be a number
  },
  validationSchema: {
    name: Yup.string().required(),
    height: Yup.number().required() // should error, as height does not exist on initialValues
    // error because we are missing the age property and its validation here
  }
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish such a constraint in typescript, without having to predefine the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible, in this case, to make standalone type with negation. In order to make it work, in typescript, you usually need to use function arguments inference.
See example:

```js
import Yup from 'yup'

interface Section<T, U extends T> {
    initialValues: T;
    validationSchema: U;
}

const sectionBuilder = <T, U extends T>(section: Section<T, T & U>) => {

}

sectionBuilder({
    initialValues: { name: 'hello' },
    validationSchema: { name: 'john' } // ok
})

sectionBuilder({
    initialValues: { name: 'hello' },
    validationSchema: { age: 42 } // expected error
})

sectionBuilder({
    initialValues: { name: 'hello' },
    validationSchema: { name: 'john', age: 42 } // expected error
})
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wjn41w)

Generic `U` in `Section` is an intersection of `T` and `U` or in other words, `U` is a set of properties which are common for `initialValues` and `validationSchema`

Comment: Amazing.  And I'm guessing `sectionBuilder` simply returns the same value as its argument?  We're just using the function because its easier to constrain types with a function argument?

Comment: @SethLutske absolutely yes. I have used a function only for argument inference